# Laravel - Use timezone manually without relaying on server timezone configuration

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel and I have problem with the server time configuration.

That means that the no matter what timezone I set laravel configuration to, The server time will always be 1 hour and 12 minutes ahead of the current timezone.

**My question is** - there any temporary/quickfix I can make in order to get the right hour and minute without relaying on the server timezones which are incorrect?

- I know this is not problem of Laravel, but I need some quick fix ideas until I'll set up a new server or fix this issue. Any way to decrease 1 hour and 12 minutes to the laravel timezone?

Comment: You can change the timezone PHP uses, but that won't correct a 12 minute offset on the server. You need to get the server time fixed.

Comment: What is your `timezone` (see in config/app.php) ? and try to execute `date` on your cmd

Comment: My timezone is `'timezone' => 'Asia/Jerusalem',`. The time here is `17:33` and server time is `18:45`. this configuration works in my localhost.

Comment: @TrongLamPhan I have no CMD, this is linux server and I dont have access to such as things beside directadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you have the difference of 1, 2 or 3 hours, you can change your timezone to get it right but with 1h12 there's no way to have a configuration of laravel to do that.

So, we'll use php to do that for you. Create a helper file `helpers.php`under `app/`. In this file, create the following function:

```
function getCurrentTime()
{
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 4320);
}
```

Then, you must config your `composer.json` to autoload your `helpers.php`:

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
    ...
}
```

and you must run `composer dump-autoload` to make it work.

From now, you can call `getCurrentTime()` at any moment, it'll give you the time you desire.

Comment: Problematic, since my application is based on the laravel create_at and updated_at fields created by laravel! :(

Comment: Yeah, i know it's not easy to use but because it's a fix, so when you have a `insert`, `update` query, use `getCurrentTime()` for `created_at`, `updated_at` fields instead of `Carbon::now()`. When you have a `select` query, try to write a new function like `getTime($time)` to get your $time right.

Comment: But i think you should ask the server administrator for help, to make your code clean.